# Eclipse is not creating structure for Enterprise Application Projects

Tags: eclipse, ejb

When creating a New Enterprise Application Project, instead of creating the usual tree with:
    +Deployment Descriptor
    +JAX-WS WebServices
    +ejbModule
    +JRE System Library
    +JBoss v5.1
    +EAR Libraries
    +JavaScript Resources
    +build

Eclipse is creating only a very simple structure. Like This:

+JavaScript Resources

Only the `.settings` folder and `.project` file are being created in the project's folder. No source, etc.

What's going on with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds more like you're listing the contents of a View rather than what's actually in your project.  There isn't actually a "JavaScript Resources" folder, it's a root node under which the project's known types and globals are browsable.  Have you checked the Project Explorer view (Window->Show View)?

Comment: The contents in the folder of my project are only `.settings` and `project`. I'm listing the contents on the Package Explorer, where I usually browse the contents of my projects. They're all showing up perfectly fine in the same workspace, as long as they're not Enterprise Application Projects.

Comment: The Package Explorer will only show Java classes and plain files, not the nodes you mention are missing.  For that you'll need the Project (or Enterprise) Explorer.